# Подгрузка данных через ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, wordpress, javascript

Подгружаю посты через ajax. Появилась необходимость подгружать их не только на главной странице, но и на странице поиска, а так же на страницах категорий. В итоге, подгрузка на главной странице работала великолепно, а именно код был таков:

```
function page_ujax_func() { 
global $post;   
$tmp_post = $post;
$paged = $_POST['pagenumber']; //получаем номер страницы которую будем подгружать
$next_posts = get_posts('paged='.$paged); //получаем посты из полученого нмера страницы
foreach($next_posts as $post): setup_postdata($post); //выводим их циклом
?>
<div class="announce_pr" >
<div id="left-announce">
<div class="cover"><?if(sizeof($post->files)): $img = array_shift($post->files);?><a href="<? the_permalink()?>"><img src="<?=$img->thumbnail?>" /></a><?else :?><img width="131" height="97" src="img/noimg.jpg" /><?endif?></div>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <p class="opisanie"><?php the_content(); ?></p>
</div>
<div class="price"><span class="price_padd"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ads_price1', true); ?> $</span><br /><span class="price_padd"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ads_price2', true); ?> €</span>
</div>
<div id="clear"></div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; 
exit;
}
$post = $tmp_post;
```

Этот код полностью работоспособен. Но когда я указываю условные теги для проверки страницы, на которой будем подгружать посты получаю ошибку Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() на 76 линии.

```
    function page_ujax_func() { 
    if( is_home()) {  //если главная то подгружать также как и в первом коде
        $paged = $_POST['pagenumber'];
    $next_posts = get_posts('paged='.$paged);
    }
    else if(is_category()) { //если мы в категории, то подгружать посты из категории $cat_ID 
        $paged = $_POST['pagenumber'];
    $cat_ID = get_query_var('cat');
    $next_posts = get_posts('paged='.$paged.'&cat='.$cat_ID);    
    }
    else if(is_search()) { //если мы на поиске подгружаем посты по кейворду $keywords
        $paged = $_POST['pagenumber'];
        $keywords = get_search_query();
       $next_posts = get_posts('paged='.$paged.'&s='.$keywords);     
    }
    global $post;   
    $tmp_post = $post;
    foreach($next_posts as $post): setup_postdata($post);
    ?>
    <div class="announce_pr" >
    <div id="left-announce">
    <div class="cover"><?if(sizeof($post->files)): $img = array_shift($post->files);?><a href="<? the_permalink()?>"><img src="<?=$img->thumbnail?>" /></a><?else :?><img width="131" height="97" src="img/noimg.jpg" /><?endif?></div>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <p class="opisanie"><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="price"><span class="price_padd"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ads_price1', true); ?> $</span><br /><span class="price_padd"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ads_price2', true); ?> €</span>
    </div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; 
    exit;
    }
    $post = $tmp_post;
```

Теперь не работает даже подгрузка на главной. Я так понимаю, что это if не работает? Сам код находится в functions.php. Помогите как решить проблему.Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$post = $tmp_post;` поставьте перед функцией!

И в принципе, почему бы не сделать так

```
function page_ujax_func($post, $paged)
{
    //код функции
}
```

В итоге избавляетесь от

1. `global $post;`
2. `$_POST['pagenumber'];` input может быть переименован на любой другой в html'е, не переписывать же N-ое количество функций изза этого
3. и еще пары лишних переменных.

Просто удобно вызываем функцию и передаем в нее значения `page_ujax_func($post, $_POST['pagenumber']);`

А в вашем случае, функция служит не более чем оберткой кода.

Comment: Так это же wordpress, эта функция вызывается при запросе. Что-нибудь как решить ошибку скажете?)

Comment: > Так это же wordpress

так это же не значит что нужно быдлокодить))

---------------------------

`$post = $tmp_post; поставьте перед функцией!`

Comment: ахах, я поправлю, обещаю. $post = $tmp_post; перед функцией поставил - ошибка.

Comment: Посмотрите что возвращает переменная `$next_posts`

Comment: В общем выяснил, что если обоим условиям написать одно и то же значение, то ошибка сохраняется. Значит не получается пройти проверку на if, if else...Если не проходит проверку, значит и нету $next_posts и следовательно ругается foreach.